# How to change permalink on post click on post listing page

Tags: posts, permalinks

I have a posts listing page, my requirement is that I want to change the url on the click of the post and expand the post to full detail. I am not sure if this can be done without refresh.
Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to using jquery function functionality

```
<script>
var current_main = window.location.pathname;
var current= document.URL;
//var lastElement = current.substr(current.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var main_url = currentq+"?"+thechosenone+"="+thechosenone;
var main =  history.pushState(current,"", main_url );
</script>
```

by using this you can able to append the url's with specified get methods.
I hope this will help you